# How to always display as Day view on shared outlook html calendar?

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, outlook-restapi

i like to share my outlook calendar with my team, and i have shared outlook calendar html link which i have iframed in to an html file. the calendar shows up but always in the week view but i want to show it as the day view.

> current view:

[image: Week View]
below is the html code (i have removed id from the source link for privacy)
this page will be loaded in to a raspberry Pi which is connected to a small LCD screen to display my availability.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Shared Calendar</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body 
    {
      color:#000000;
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
      background-image:url('Background Image');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    a  { color:#0000FF; }
    a:visited { color:#800080; }
    a:hover { color:#008000; }
    a:active { color:#FF0000; }
    -->
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<iframe style="width: 768px; height: 1366px; overflow: hidden;" src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/somethinghere/anotherhere/calendar.html" width="800" height="1200" scrolling="no">Iframes not supported</iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Expected view:

[image: Day View]

Comment: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/19051456-week-view-link-to-html-published-calendar